# C strings building

Tags: c, sockets, c-strings

I have following problem, in my code i'm trying to build response header in `HTTP` protocol. I don't understend why my code doesn't work. Function build response content in buffer, and write them to socket file descriptor:

```
void write_fd( struct http_response* response, int client_socket )
{
   int length = strlen(response->file_content + MAX_HEADER_LENGTH );
   char response_content[length];
   response_content[0] = '\0';

   printf("-- Descriptor %i, start responding\n", client_socket );

   write_fd_resp_line( response, response_content ); 
   //printf("%s\n", response_content); - "HTTP/1.1 GET OK\n"
   write_fd_date( response_content );
   //printf("%s\n", response_content); - Segmentation Fault
   write_fd_server_name( response_content );
   write_fd_con_type( response, response_content );
   write_fd_doc_content( response, response_content );  

   int sended = 0;
   int content_length = strlen(response_content) + 1;
   int n;
   while( sended != content_length ) {
       n = write( client_socket, response_content + sended, content_length - sended );
       if( n <= 0 ) break;
       sended += n;
       printf("-- Descriptor - %i, sended %i/%i\n", client_socket, sended, content_length );
   }
```

}

but when i'm changed:

```
char response_content[length];
```

to

```
char* response_content = malloc(length);
```

function works, server writes response content to socket, but after that i getting Segmentation Fault. I'm don't understand why.

Function with pattern `write_fd_*` looks similar to:

```
void write_fd_resp_line( http_response* response, char* response_content ) 
{
    char *tmp;
    char code_str[4]; 
    tmp = (char*) get_status_code_name(response->code);
    snprintf( code_str, 4, "%d", response->code );
    strcat( response_content, HTTP_VERSION );
    strcat( response_content, " ");
    strcat( response_content, code_str );
    strcat( response_content, " " );
    strcat( response_content, tmp );
    strcat( response_content, "\n");
}
```

Comment: is this a typo `strlen(response->file_content + MAX_HEADER_LENGTH );` -> `strlen(response->file_content) + MAX_HEADER_LENGTH;`?

Comment: @iharob I somewhat suspect that is a significant source of the OP's woes.

Comment: you're right! I didn't saw that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo, but interestingly the code is compiling for sure

```
int length = strlen(response->file_content + MAX_HEADER_LENGTH );
```

it should be

```
int length = strlen(response->file_content) + MAX_HEADER_LENGTH;
```

the reason why the code is compiling is because what this means

```
response->file_content + MAX_HEADER_LENGTH
```

is pass the `response->file_content` pointer incremented by `MAX_HEADER_LENGTH`, which is valid, but very likely incorrect, and very probably the cause of the segmentation falult.